# Is there any note for the second half of Friedberg's linear algebra like Terry Tao's?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I used [Tao's notes](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2016/12/linear-algebra-notes.pdf) to learn Friedberg's linear algebra and felt that it was very useful. But the notes only for the first half of this book? Is there any similar notes for the second half?